# I honestly have no clue how to formulate this pass-by-reference conundrum

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

So here's what I see this code doing:

- An array is made
- A loop iterates 10 times

  - A new array is created
  - A reference to this new array is saved in the first array
- 10 arrays now reside in the original array with values 0, 1, 2, 3...

What really happens:

- WTF?

Code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

$arrays = array();

foreach(range(0, 10) as $i)
{
    $arr = array();
    $arr[0] = $i;

    $arrays[] = &$arr;
}

print_r($arrays);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

)
```

I would like to know exactly why apparently only the 10th array is referred to ten times, instead of every instance of the arrays being referred to one each.

Also if somebody who isn't just thinking WTF (like me) would like to edit the title, feel free to do so.

Comment: No quarrels with the title, @deceze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
$arr = array();
```

does not create a new array but rather assigns an empty array to the already existing reference.
If you want the variable name to "point" to a *different* array in memory, you have to `unset()` (or "disconnect") it first before assigning an empty array to it:

```
foreach(range(0, 10) as $i)
{
    unset($arr);
    $arr = array();
    $arr[0] = $i;

    $arrays[] = &$arr;
}
```

This is because the only operations that can make a variable point to something else is the reference assignment (`=&`) and the `unset()`.

Comment: I see... I don't see why, but I see... +1. I'm still holding out for a more thorough explanation as to WHY

Comment: Ok, cheers. By the way nice number of badges :-) It's identical to my own

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that by inserting a *reference* to `$arr` inside `$arrays`, you are effectively adding the exact same array 10 times -- and each reference to the array has the value last assigned to it (i.e. the one produced when `$i` is 10).

It's not clear what you intend to achieve by inserting a *reference* in each iteration -- either removing the `&` or putting `unset($arr)` at the beginning of the loop would give you the expected behavior. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is obviously just a test case of the issue. In my actual application I need to save references to my arrays at different locations for later use. It's really not that hard to imagine use cases for this. Evidently my error was to assume that `array()` actually created a **new** instance of something, much like an instantiation would

Comment: @Codemonkey: I have needed to do this myself, so yes, use cases exist but it doesn't hurt to question the status quo. It looks like `unset` is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way. You do `$arrays[] = &$arr;` 10 times. This stores a reference to the local variable `$arr` 10 times. Since it's the same variable (the variable's scope is the entire function), it stores the same reference all 10 times. Thus, why should you expect the 10 elements to be different?

The reference you are storing has nothing to do with the *value* of `$arr`; it just has to do with the *variable* `$arr`. When you print the reference it prints the value of `$arr` at that time.

Comment: I assumed `array()` would change the address of the variable just like a class instantiation would

Comment: @Codemonkey: Nothing changes the address of a variable. Objects are reference types. So when you initialize an object you get a pointer and you assign that pointer to a variable. The address of the variable doesn't change even when you change the value by assigning another pointer.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're storing a *reference* to the array that `$arr` points to in the array. And you keep overwriting that array with the latest number. All references in `$arr` will point to the same array in the end.

I don't know what you expect to get out of this in the end, but getting rid of `&` should fix this behavior.

Comment: Well obviously getting rid of the & will "fix" the behaviour. The problem is that I really need the behaviour. Could you explain exactly why all references to `$arr` will point to the same array in the end? Doesn't `array()` create a new array? Imagine I replaced `array()` with `new ArrayObject()` - that works. Why does that work, and not the pass-by-reference array?

Comment: `$arr = array()` does not create a new array, it *assigns* an empty array to the variable `$arr`. Anything that's referencing `$arr` will thereby be overwritten as well. What do you need that behavior for? Why references?

Comment: If I need to refer to the same array from multiple locations, do I have any option but to use references?

Comment: What do you need it for? References are only useful if you keep two variables with different names that refer to the same data. You do not keep this second variable, you only keep one `$arr` which you keep overwriting.

Comment: I'd be happy to demonstrate it: https://gist.github.com/2216437. I need to keep track of certain rows to insert stuff into them at a later point in my loop